# Converting geometry point to lat/long in Geodjango app

Tags: django, openlayers, latitude-longitude, point, geodjango

I'm creating a web mapping application using Django, Geodjango, OpenLayers and PostGIS. I want to zoom on an OpenLayers basemap to the location of a city that has been selected from a combo box and I figure I can do this by passing lat/long coordinates and a zoom level to OpenLayers.

I have a view function that runs a django query with a filter for the selected city and then I calculate the centroid for the returned QuerySet, as shown below.

```
centroid = LGA.objects.get(name=lga).geom.centroid
```

The way I am currently setting my map centre is statically with the following code:

```
var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(133.0, -27.0).transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    map.getProjectionObject()
    );
```

Those coordinates are for the centre of Australia, but I want to set the map centre dynamically for a selected city using a Django template with variables for the Lat and Long. I'm not sure how to get the Lat and Long from the centroid I calculate in my view function, or alternatively, if there is another way to set the map centre in OpenLayers by passing it a geometry rather than coordinates.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Ro

Answer (score 7):

Ah, I figured it out and it was so simple. You can access the Lat and Long values simply by adding '.x' or '.y' to the end of the django query as follows:

```
centroid = LGA.objects.get(name=lga).geom.centroid.x
```

Comment: You're fetching the `x` or `y` property of the `GeometryField` instance. Saying `adding '.x' or '.y' to the end of the django query` kind of makes it misleading.

Comment: Perhaps deserves more clarification:

Comment: `latitude = GEOSGeometry.centroid.y` `longitude = GEOSGeometry.centroid.x`. The order in your post makes it sound like lat = x and lon = y which is incorrect most times.

Answer (score 0):

What is your geometry point formatting? Can you provide us an example?
In my understanding, your geometry point is not in projection **[EPSG:4236](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4236/)**(which is for Latitude and Longitude) but other formatting (projection) right? The normal way is convert projection in Openlayers using **[Point.transform](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.transform)** method, but not be calculated in GeoDjango.

Comment: for example google map use projection EPSG:900913, so if you want convert a geometry point from google map to Lon/Lat, you can do: point.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I edited my question to give a bit more detail and added the code for how I am currently setting my map centre. I'd like to do this dynamically based on the city selected. My city geometries are stored in EPSG 4326. I'm trying to find a way to go from the geometry point to Long/Lat to dynamically set the centre, unless there is another way...?

Comment: Base on your new post now I know what you want, good to see geom.centroid.x works for you, the other way is doing it on opnelayers like this: var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(centroid.x, centroid.y); map.setCenter(lonlat, 5);  Please pay attention "centroid" is the geometry point you passed by AJAX from Django query.

Comment: btw, these two links will help you understand what I mean: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html and http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html